# Comment multiple line in xml file using shortcut

Tags: xml, eclipse

We can comment multiple line in xml using below,

```
<!-- comment lines

 -->
```

Can anyone please let me know if we can do this using a shortcut in Eclipse (Neon 4.6.1). If yes what is this shortcut ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mac try <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. This works for most of the editors/IDE.

Answer (score 1):

For commenting multiple lines, you can use

Ctrl + Shift + /

Comment: No mention Vijay

Comment: Accept answer @Vijay :P